# Other users keep closing my questions

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I have tried and been twice refused to post what I consider to be a reasonable JavaScript-related question on Stack Exchange.  When refused, someone suggested the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site, which I thought was going to accept my question, but alas no.

I have noticed many helpful posts on Stack Exchange have a rejection notice lately, questions that have provided a useful answer to what I was looking for as a developer.

Comment: From what I see, you received cordial comments and even an answer on your previous question. Stackoverflow is not for technology recommendation, You can read that in the FAQs.

Comment: FWIW, the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) does have this: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." So that would explain why your first question was put on hold. I can't speak for the other question you asked.

Comment: The suggestion to move it to Software Recs was a terrible suggestion which should never have been made without providing further information on what kinds of questions that site expects. I've deleted that comment. Having said that, it doesn't make your question any more on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Could someone please post a link to the question in question?

Comment: [Here's the SO one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762079/javascript-cross-platform-architecture). It pretty much ticks the no library box, personal opinion and being too broad.

Comment: Thanks, @Andy (I didn't realize the "migrated" link would take me there, indirectly). And I agree, the question has all those problems. It's not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Good work by @Jamal in eliminating the Nazi embellishments in the question too.

Comment: @Andy What am I, chopped liva? :P

Comment: @kojiro No; you haven't been chopped, yet!

Answer (score 9):

Without context this is not a good question in itself... if you have an opinion please try to prove it. Everyone is more than willing to take criticism on board but it has to be valid. When you're talking to thousands of people who've spent years trying to keep the site clean a rant about Nazis isn't necessarily the best way to get agreement.

Having said that, this can be a difficult site to work with. Everything is about the content; that's why it's so successful. So, the content Nazis are protecting their community.

If your question is put on hold I highly recommend reading the help pages and attempting to improve it so it's within the site guidelines. You'll be surprised at the amount of help you'll receive.

Answer (score 7):

[Closed] or [On Hold] or whatever they call it these days is not a rejection notice. It's an opportunity to improve the question. Often, a quick edit, showing your own approach to a problem or giving more detail on the problem is sufficient. The close reason can be a good clue. Some StackExchanges allow more opinionated questions than others, so try to be aware of the rules of the particular SE.